# Can I use a javascript file from an html template in react js?

Tags: reactjs

I've created an HTML template. And I have a javascript file for this design. Javascript file, such as popup to open the process. How do I use this javascript file in react js? I'm importing it at the top of the page I'm going to use because this compiles the javascript file every time the page is opened, there are performance problems. How can I do this best? I am waiting for your answers. Thank you

Comment: Can you please share the source code that you have tried.

Comment: @MayankBansal I called the script address in index.html in the public directory, it was not. At the top of the page I called import '../../public/app.min.js'. never again

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.
To do this, you need to put your javascript file url or path in public/index.html file inside the head tag.

Comment: but it doesn't give a result